# How do I update a SP user's email address (version 2003)

Tags: email, 2003

I have been asked to update a users email address (for their alerts from SP).  I am using version 2003 and I am not 100% sure of my role (long story).

Anyway, I don't seem to have access to do this.  It's not under 'site settings'.

Please note I do not have access to the server side, Powershell or Central Administration.

Should I send a request 'request access' - that's under 'Welcome' then my name.

The user is getting alerts from two different SP sites.

New to Sharepoint admin.

Answer (score 1):

unless you have some strange set up, the email change should happen in Active directory. Sharepoint inherits that surely between 30min or max 24 hours (when the next incremental synch happens).

It is not something you can do, you need to ask active directory people to update the email of this person.